# Different UINavigationBar height on iOS8

Tags: ios8, uinavigationbar

I'm running two separate apps on iOS8. In the screen shot below you can see that the `UINavigationBar` on the left has a height greater then the one on the right. What could be the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: i can't understand your problem please elaborate your question.

Comment: In the red section , the different app has differet hight navigationBar. please tell me why .

Comment: both app are provide by ios ?

Comment: @Devanshi YES, the image is screenshot by double click iphone  HomeButton. I run two demo app，I found  that two app are different navigationBar height。app's navigationBar hieght on the left side is more tall than the right. (PS:I am chinese，I am so sorry that my English is so bad :)

Comment: if your iPhone is iPhone 6 then i think the app with green color is customised for iPhone 6, 6+ whereas the app with white color is not customised

Comment: @Aanabidden, thank you very much. I sovled this issue by your inspiration .

Comment: This edit improves clarity of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the toolbar delegate. Then in your view controller, implement `UIBarPositioningDelegate`. Implement it as follows:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

and

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` in viewDidLoad